# How to change the value of another component property? (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a mane page that have a button that triggers a pop up box to appear:

```
  <i class="material-icons" (click)="openPopUp()">info</i>
```

openPopUp() is just setting the property to true:

```
openPopUp() {
    this.showPopup = true;
  }
```

and then im sending the value of `showPopUp` to the PopupComponent(its separate component):

```
<div *ngIf="showPopup === true">
  <pop-up-info-box [componentBPopUp]="showPopup"></pop-up-info-box>
</div>
```

but now in the componenetB i have the closePopUp func that is triggered from the html:

close

and is just setting the componentBPopUp to be false:

```
 @Input
  public componentBPopUp: boolean;

  public closePopUp() {
    this.popUp = false;
  }
```

but what actually need to be set to false is the `showPopup` in the first component...how do I set its value properly?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use @Output in componentBPopUp.

for example:

```
  close(){
    this.showPopup = false;
  }
```

Example of what you trying to do:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kUWrlnoXgJ15rXObdaqh?p=preview

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 2):

What you should do in ComponentB is to raise an event on close.

```
@Output() onClose: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();


public closePopUp() {
    this.onClose.emit(true);
}
```

Now on the parent just subscribe to this event:

```
<div *ngIf="showPopup === true">
  <pop-up-info-box [componentBPopUp]="showPopup" (onClose)="showPopup = false">   
  </pop-up-info-box>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To your question a parent component can refer to a child component using the [`@ViewChild` decorator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

```
@ViewChild('popup')
popup: ModalComponent;

this.popup.doStuff();

<div  *ngIf="showPopup === true">
  <pop-up-info-box #popup [componentBPopUp]="showPopup"></pop-up-info-box>
</div>
```

But your specific problem can be solved with two-way data binding between the componentBPopUp and the showPopup field (see [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html))

Another option is to use EventEmmiter to notify the other component of the change (see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html))